# Can the demand curve be a rectangular hyperbola, but $E_D \neq 1$?

Tags: supply-and-demand, elasticity, price, demand

So, I am given the next table:
[image]

I am asked to find $Q_D$.
So the prerequisites to find $Q_D$ is that the price must change, and all other factors of demand must be steady. So, I can find the $Q_D$ between A and C. Our professor stated that, as $P_A Q_A= P_C Q_C =20000$ , the demand curve is a rectangular hyperbola and $Q_D = \frac{20.000}{P}$. However, in the rectangular hyperbola, $E_D=-1$ in every point of the demand curve, but here we have that $E_{D}=-0,8$. Is there something I am missing? Does $E_D=-0.8  \neq -1$ imply that the curve is a line or not? Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps $E_D$ does not denote point elasticity, but this is unclear. This a valid question, but it is between you and your professor, you should raise it with her.

Comment: @Giskard Ok, thanks for the recommendation, I will ask my professor for more insight. If the elasticity was $E_{D_{A \rightarrow C}}$, then would that make sense? I mean, we know that the point elasticity equals 1 in any given point, but what about when we go from A to C? Does the same rule still apply?

Comment: Point elasticity is only defined in points.

Comment: @KennyLJ Income ($Y$) is different.

Comment: @Giskard Ok, so if it was $E_{D_{A \rightarrow C}}$, then we don't have any problem right? Because as you mentioned $E_D=1$, only in points, and not when moving between them? I am sorry, for asking again, but that's a very vague point for me.

Comment: @george.zrs I don't really understand your question. Please raise it with your professor, this discussion should really happen between the two of you.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try a linear demand function, so $Q=a-bP$. Then $\epsilon_A=\frac{\partial Q}{\partial P}\frac{P_A}{Q_A}=-b\frac{P_A}{Q_A}$, so $b=-\epsilon_A\frac{Q_A}{P_A}=0.8\frac{500}{40}=10$. Then $a=Q_A+bP_A=500+10\cdot 40=900$. Thus, your table is compatible with the demand function $Q_D=900-10P$.

Comment: This was the exact way I solved it in the first place, but my according to my professor this is wrong. I will ask for more insight on this question however, and I will keep you updated!

Comment: Your professor is obviously wrong and should admit that. You cannot use two data points to reconstruct a complete curve, but his suggestion (the rectangular hyperbola) is even worse since it is not compatible with the given elasticity, as you correctly observed.